# Designing code so that I can benefit of overloading methods

Tags: java, overloading, java-11

I'm trying to solve the following problem

Current code:

```
interface Translatable {
   void translate(String a);
}

class A implements Translatable{
    void translate(String a){}
}

class B implements Translatable{
    void translate(String a){}
}

class C implements Translatable{
    void translate(String a){}
}
```

I would like to obtain something like this in Java 11

```
interface Translatable {

    void translate(String a);

    void translate(String a, int b);
}


class A implements Translatable{
    void translate(String a, int b){}
}

class B implements Translatable{
    void translate(String a){}
}

class C implements Translatable{
    void translate(String a){}
}
```

Basically not all the classes implementing "Translatable" need the new param

How can I organize my classes so I obtain this without duplicating my code? Thank you

Comment: Unrelated, regarding naming: dont use Hungarian notation. Do not put that **i** in front of your interface names. For the actual question: how are those interface methods related? Could one of them have a default implementation that invokes the other method for example? You see, there are no generic answers to such problems. In order to really help you, we need more context resp. to really understand your requirements: what problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I've edited the code. THanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

**One approach**

You can make use of one of the solid principles, wich is Interface Segregation. Following it a class shouldn't have to implement a method that it doesn't use.

The idea would be to break up the Translate interface into smaller(s) interface(s).

```
interface Translatable {
    void translate(String a);
}

interface SpecificTranslatable {
    void specificTranslate(String a, int b);
}

class A implements Translatable {

    @Override
    public void translate(String a) {
        System.out.println("simple translation");
    }
}

class B implements Translatable, SpecificTranslatable {

    @Override
    public void translate(String a) {
        System.out.println("simple translation");
    }

    @Override
    public void specificTranslate(String a, int b) {
        System.out.println("specific translation");
    }
}
```

Comment: this might be a solution , but looking back to my "wanted" code I would like to call translate method(with one or two parameters), depending on the instance of the object . Not sure if this is possible or how can I re-model my code so I could obtain that. Thank you

Comment: And you don’t want to give up the interface right ? For example changing it to a parent class

Comment: I would like to keep the interface if possible.